# Finding a substring in an URL with nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I have the simple following code :

```
var S = require('string');

function matchBlacklist(inputString) {
    var blacklist = ["facebook", "wikipedia", "search.ch", "local.ch"];
    var found = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < blacklist.length; i++) {

        if (S(inputString).contains(blacklist[i]) > -1) {
            found = true;
        }
    }
    return (found);
}

matchBlacklist("www.facebook.com/this_is_a_test"); // returns true
matchBlacklist("www.example.com/this_is_a_test"); // returns true
```

But it always returns true; as it should return false for the second case

Comment: Perhaps a loop structure issue, perhaps instead of `found = true;` and then continuing with the for loop, why not just `return true;` to exit the loop?

Comment: i wonder why using ` require('string');` when string prototype already have what you need

Comment: I'd also use the built-in [URL](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_strings_and_url_objects) package if I wanted to separate various aspects of the URL to search on (host/path?query etc)

Answer (score 4):

You should test for `if(string.includes(substring)){ ... }` and not `if(string.includes(substring) > -1 ){ ... }`

but here's a more elegant one-liner :

```js
const blacklist = ["facebook", "wikipedia", "search.ch", "local.ch"];

const matchBlacklist = inputString => blacklist.some(word => inputString.includes(word))

console.log( matchBlacklist("www.facebook.com/this_is_a_test") ); // returns true
console.log( matchBlacklist("www.example.com/this_is_a_test") ); // returns false
```

Answer (score 2):

A better approach using the `find` method of arrays, which return the element if the expression evaluates `true` else undefined, then return a boolean based on the result of the find

[Find method MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

[Includes method MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```js
function matchBlacklist(inputString) {
    var blacklist = ["facebook", "wikipedia", "search.ch", "local.ch"];
    
    return !!blacklist.find(b => inputString.includes(b))
}

console.log(matchBlacklist("www.facebook.com/this_is_a_test"));
console.log(matchBlacklist("www.example.com/this_is_a_test"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "indexOf" instead "contains" method. "contains" method will return boolean value, so you cannot compare the boolean value with a number. "indexOf" will return a index number of a string, so you can do the comparison here.

```
var S = require('string');

function matchBlacklist(inputString) {
  var blacklist = ["facebook", "wikipedia", "search.ch", "local.ch"];
  var found = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < blacklist.length; i++) {

    if (S(inputString).indexOf(blacklist[i]) > -1) {
        found = true;
    }
  }
  return (found);
```

}

```
matchBlacklist("www.facebook.com/this_is_a_test"); // returns true
matchBlacklist("www.example.com/this_is_a_test"); // returns truetes
```

Comment: the main problem with this method is that if the blacklist is 1000 words long, it will go through every single word every time, even if the first word is a match, wasting 999 CPU cycles. Not to mention it will call the `S()` function, whatever that is, 999 useless times, because its output is always the same.